# What is wrong with my mySQL query? Left Join/Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql

Basically this script exports all of the orders in our little system to a CSV file. There are 4 separate tables that are joined to complete this. SEorder, SEtracking, SE_user, users_orders.

Here is the error:

```
<div id="Error">An error occurred in script '/home/sites/mywebsite.com/web/administration/allorders.php' on line 81:
<br />Undefined index:  UserLast
```

Here is my database query:

```
    //Make the query-select all orders
$query2 ="SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, Basket, Title, FirstName, LastName, Suffix, Company, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, GiftCard, GiftCardMsg, t.Tracking, u.UserFirst, u.UserLast AS doo ".
"FROM SEorder o ".
"LEFT JOIN SEtracking t ON (o.OrderID = t.OrderID) ".
"INNER JOIN users_orders uo ON (uo.OrderID = o.OrderID) ".
"INNER JOIN SEuser u ON (u.UserID = uo.UserID) ".
"AND Submitted='Y' ".
"ORDER BY OrderDate ASC";
```

and here is my php to grab the data. this is line 81 that is throwing the error:

```
$username = $row['UserFirst'] . " " . $row['UserLast'];
```

I am positive that the table SEuser exists, has the column UserLast, and that column has data in it. I am not completely versed on JOIN's though so am I missing something here? I did not create this script, just troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh thanks guys. Just needed some fresh eyes. I deleted a couple fields from that query after UserLast and didnt even look at that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aliased the `UserLast` column as `doo`.

Answer (score 0):

because you have queried the `UserLast` as `doo`
so use the `doo` index not `UserLast`

Answer (score 0):

`u.UserLast AS doo`

Your PHP should say `$row['doo']`